# Prevent nested if statements when result is dependent on the several conditions javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

[Avoiding several nested if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896916/avoiding-several-nested-if-statements)

The above is a link to a similar problem to which I am experiencing. So suppose I have an JavaScript object that takes the form:

```
var query = {
        minPrice : 30,
        maxPrice : 50,
        category : "Clothing"
    };
```

The properties for the query object comes from input elements of a HTML page. I can't think of any other way to check each permutation of minPrice, maxPrice and category without using this nested if statement structure. Is there a more elegant or better performant method?

```
if (queryParams.minPrice) {
    if (queryParams.maxPrice) {
        if (queryParams.category) {
            // minPrice, maxPrice and category
        } else {    
            // minPrice and maxPrice
        }
    } else if (queryParams.category) {
        // minPrice and category
    } else {
        // minPrice only
        console.log('minPrice');
        collection.find({price : {$gte: queryParams.minPrice}}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            console.log(docs);  
        }); 
    }
} else if (queryParams.maxPrice) {
    if (queryParams.category) {
        // maxPrice and category
    } else {
        // maxPrice only
    }   
} else {
    // category only
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
function renderMenu(container, storeInstance){
    // NOTE: perhaps this is the correct way to empty a container.. Use to 
    // refactor code..
    while (container.lastChild) container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    if (!container._filters) {
        // Query object
        container._filters = {
            minPrice: null,
            maxPrice: null,
            category: ''
        };
        container._refresh = function(){
            storeInstance.queryProducts(container._filters, function(err, products){
                    if (err){
                        alert('Error occurred trying to query products');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        displayed = Object.keys(products);
                        renderProductList(document.getElementById('productView'), storeInstance);
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    var box = document.createElement('div'); container.appendChild(box);
        box.id = 'price-filter';
        var input = document.createElement('input'); box.appendChild(input);
            input.type = 'number';
            input.value = container._filters.minPrice;
            input.min = 0;
            input.placeholder = 'Min Price';
            input.addEventListener('blur', function(event){
                container._filters.minPrice = event.target.value;
                container._refresh();
            });

        input = document.createElement('input'); box.appendChild(input);
            input.type = 'number';
            input.value = container._filters.maxPrice;
            input.min = 0;
            input.placeholder = 'Max Price';
            input.addEventListener('blur', function(event){
                container._filters.maxPrice = event.target.value;
                container._refresh();
            });

    var list = document.createElement('ul'); container.appendChild(list);
        list.id = 'menu';
        var listItem = document.createElement('li'); list.appendChild(listItem);
            listItem.className = 'menuItem' + (container._filters.category === '' ? ' active': '');
            listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('All Items'));
            listItem.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                container._filters.category = '';
                container._refresh()
            });
    var CATEGORIES = [ 'Bedroom', 'Kitchen', 'Office', 'Bathroom' ];
    for (var i in CATEGORIES){
        var listItem = document.createElement('li'); list.appendChild(listItem);
            listItem.className = 'menuItem' + (container._filters.category === CATEGORIES[i] ? ' active': '');
            listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(CATEGORIES[i]));
            listItem.addEventListener('click', (function(i){
                return function(event){
                    container._filters.category = CATEGORIES[i];
                    container._refresh();
                }
            })(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of those commented blocks like? I see the lone `minPrice`, but what about the others (at least a couple of them)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Those comments are to indicate which properties are in the query object. For example

var query = {
        minPrice : null,
        maxPrice : null,
        category : "Clothing"
    };

Then that you would be in that section where it's commented as "category only".

Comment: Yes, it's clear what the if branches are narrowing down, but what is the actual *content* of those blocks? They're not just empty, are they? Please post the real code

Comment: @user3100570 Please show us what the actual code looks like. We need to know how how you actually use the `maxPrice` and `category` in the query in order to show you how to simplify this.

Comment: Also, I can only presume you are using MongoDB here. You should have tagged your question with that, and not HTML or CSS since it has nothing to do with those.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't yet obliged our request for more code, so I'm going to take a guess at how your query works. Please adjust as needed. The idea is that you can start off with an empty query object, and add properties to it depending on which parameters are specified:

```
var query = {};

if (queryParams.minPrice || queryParams.maxPrice) {
    var price = {};

    if (queryParams.minPrice) { price.$gte = queryParams.minPrice; }
    if (queryParams.maxPrice) { price.$lte = queryParams.maxPrice; }

    query.price = price;
}

if (queryParams.category) { query.category = category; }

collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);  
});
```

Comment: I have edited the code to show where it is being used. The query object will always have those three properties as it reads it from input elements that are always displayed on the client and values changed if there was an input. Hope that clarifies my problem more. :)

Comment: @user3100570 Thank you for adding more code, but what we were really asking for was the parts that were substituted with comments in your initial code. In any case, I think the above will accomplish what you need. Can you give it a try?

Answer (score -1):

Use `every()` and `filter()`:

```js
var query = {
  minPrice: 30,
  maxPrice: 50,
  category: "Clothing"
};

// you can use:
// Object.values()
// Object.keys()
// Object.entries()

// all three is set:
if (Object.values(query).every(e => e !== 'null')) {
  // your code
} else if (Object.values(query).filter(e => e).length === 2) {
  // maxPrice and category is set:
  if (!query.minPrice) {}
  // minPrice and category is set:
  else if (!query.maxPrice) {}
  // minPrice and maxPrice is set
  else {}
} else if (Object.values(query).filter(e => e).length === 1) {
  // only minprice is set
  if (query.minPrice) {}
  // only maxPrice is set
  else if (query.maxPrice) {}
  // only category is set
  else {}
} else {}
```

It doesn't eliminate all nesting, but makes it easier to see through.

## EDIT: another suggestion

And actually you can check only the category, if you do use some built-in constants (of course, if your code-logic allows it):

```
queryParams.minPrice = queryParams.minPrice || -Infinity;
queryParams.maxPrice = queryParams.maxPrice || Infinity;
```

This ensures that if **min-/maxPrice** is not set, then it's treated out of any bounds (no price will be higher than maxPrice, and no price will be lower than minPrice). So, you'll have to check only for **category**.

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking for. This would only do anything when _all_ of the parameters are specified. They are looking to conditionally use the parameters depending on which are specified.

Comment: Yep - OP was asking for a solution to avoid nested if statements. This avoids nested if statements (and long `&&` statements).

Comment: It sure does avoid if statements, but it doesn't remotely do what they're trying to achieve with their code.

Comment: I'd argue with that - one solution is in my snippet (I edited it so it can be seen better), only not fully worked out.

Comment: Ok, well if that was only part of what you were suggesting they do, then you would have had to say that. FYI `Object.values(query).every(e => e !== 'null')` would not work here because `'null'` is a string value.

Comment: I always think that SO is not a code writing service, but a place where you try to direct people to solutions. OP doesn't seem to be a beginner (and haven't said so), so I guessed if the core idea is given, then it can be flashed (or fleshed?) out. :)

Comment: Yes, I didn't say you had to give them the entire code, but if you were giving them part of a solution, you needed to explain that that's what you were doing, and explain where it fit into the big picture. It wasn't at all clear from your original answer.